# South migration on a new DB

Tags: python, django, django-south

I know the problem but this doesn't to make sense because I thought South would handle this.
I am trying to install a new STAGING server, so a new DB but I am getting south migration errors.

I have 2 apps, `bar` and `foo`, and below are the models.
I had a Foo dependent on Bar in the `0001_foo_initial` migrations. But then I removed `Bar` and the also dependency because i didn't need them.

```
#in foo.models
class Foo(models.Model)
    #bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar...) #dependency removed in foo 2nd migration
    foo_name..

"""bar.models - removed in bar 2nd migration
class Bar(models.Model)
     bar_name...
"""

#bar
0001_bar_initial.py - had Bar model
0002_bar_model_Bar_deleted.py - removed Bar model

#foo
0001_foo_initial.py - foo with bar dependency
0002_foo_foreign_key_bar_deleted.py - remove dependency
```

So when I ran `migrate --all` and I am getting relationship doesn't exists in `0001_foo_initial.py` because its trying to add the dependency. 
It seems it ran the `bar` migrations first, which deleted the `Bar`. It then attempts to run `0001_foo_initial` but since `Bar` is already removed, it throws the error.

How do I go about fixing this error or did I miss something. I could delete the lines that have the dependency [e.g. remove the dependency in 0001_foo_initial.py] but then I will have to do lotta house maintenance for that, e.g. I will have to remove the file `0002_foo_foreign_key_bar_deleted` since there is none.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run migrations on a new database server. Instead run `syncdb` and make your existing migrations `faked` via `migrate --fake`.

`syncdb` will create your current models structure in the database. Faking migrations is necessary for saying `south` that migrations don't need to be applied.

Hope I've explained that well.